# Не изменяет строку,выдают пустую строку

Tags: c++

С виду простая задачка, но в ходе решения возникли вопросы.

Дана строка, которую нужно скопировать в новую и дописать точки.
С использованием указателя.

Сказано - сделано.

В качестве параметров передаю 2 строки, одна заполненная, другая - строка, в которую буду копировать.

Инициализирую пустую строку.

С помощью цикла `while` прохожу по строке и копирую слова в новую строку и с помощью операторов условий добавляю символы.

Но результат - просто пустая строка. Компилятор упорно видит пустую строку.
Я циклом прохожу по всей выделенной памяти для строки и присваиваю же их в новую строку.

Возможно потерял ссылки где-то. Пошагово опять же указатель на заполненную строку всё видит прекрасно, а вторую никак не хочет копировать.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

void copystring(char* str, char* str1)
{
    char* in_str = str;
    char* out_str = str1;//используем указатели
    *out_str = ' ';
    ++out_str;

    while (*in_str == ' ')
    {
        if (*in_str == '.')
        {
            *out_str = '.';
            break;
        }

        if (*in_str != ',')
            *out_str = *in_str;
        else
        {
            *out_str = '\.';
            ++out_str;
            *out_str = ' ';
        }

        ++in_str;
        ++out_str;
    }

    cout << out_str << endl;
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    char str[100] = {"one two three four five"};
    char str1[100] = " ";
    cout << "Исходная строка" << endl;
    cout << str << endl;
    cout << "Полученная новая строка" << endl;
    copystring(str, str1);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Самое интересное то, что если всё сделать в `main`, то все правильно изменяется.

Но нужно отдельно через процедуры, поэтому и реализуем через процедуру.

Comment: а что именно вы вести хотите?.. `out_str` указывает на последний символ, разве нет? Попробуйте `str1` вывести.

Comment: Результат такой же. Пустая строка.
Изменял циклы например писал while(1) но там уже выводилось исключение.
ПО циклу while думаю правильно идём пока не будет конец строки.

Comment: @nick_n_a, не говорите глупости. Он выделил память под массивы в стеке, и до тех пор пока не закончится выполнение _tmain, она никуда не денется.

Comment: Память ок, почти. ASCIIz может быть нарушен, но  главное `cout<<"Полученная новая строка"<<endl;  copystring(str,str1);   
    system("pause");` а где **вывод на экран** str1 ?

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb  так не годится, он всегда будет пустым, потому что до этой строчки делался сдвиг **++out_str**. Вот **str1** указатель остался, к счастью автора - не тронутым - его вывести можно - это и будет верное решение.

Answer (score 1):

У вас несколько ошибок.

1. `while(*in_str== ' ')` приводит к тому, что как только символ входной строки не пробел, функция завершает работу. Это явно не то, что вы хотели. Тут нужна проверка `while(*in_str)`.
2. По окончании работы вы не записываете завершающий нулевой символ в выходную строку.
3. Выводить надо строку, на которую указывает `str1`, так как `out_str` указывает за конец этой строки.
4. По мелочи: не стоит в одной и той же функции и преобразовывать строку, и выводить. Функция - это логически завершенный кусок...

P.S. В логике ваших замен не разбирался, но она на вскользь брошенный взгляд кажется тоже несколько неверной... Но так как вы не написали, что там должно делаться - это уже на вашей совести :)